# Rhapsody c++ project with absolute paths

Tags: c++, absolute-path, rhapsody

So we are just starting out with Rhapsody. For the most part we can all get projects up and running on our own PCs, but when we attempted to work on the same project (via a shared source controlled server) we encountered the absolute paths issue.

This is our scenario:

- Developer 1 starts the project in `c:\software_development\rhaps_test\` and then commits that to a repository.
- Developer 2 checks out the project to `c:\swdev\src\rhaps_test\` - the project opens ok, but when code generation is attempted we get:

  - Directory c:\software_development\rhaps_test... does not exist - do you wish to create it?
  - If you say yes to this, it appears to attempt to write to c:\ but complains that it does not have write permissions / the folder does not exist.

So two questions are:

1. We want our code to use relative paths only - like any normal IDE : )  ... how can we do this? I can't find the settings to change
2. (and less important) Why does Rhapsody complain about permissions? - I am running as a admin on the PC and c:\ should not have any issues being written to by any user I think...

Any help / guidance much appreciated : )

Comment: Windows security is more advanced than Linux security. Admin is _not_ like root, an all-powerful account. Admins can do almost everything, but often only intentionally. The relevant concept is "elevation". You might be able to right-click Rhapsody and choose "run as administrator" - this is _not_ the default even if you're logged in with admin rights. That's only a right, not an automatism.

Comment: @MSalters ah ok +1 for a fair point. However I can open a windows explorer and create a new folder in c:\ without elevating, so it still does not make sense to me

Comment: Probably Windows 10, then - Windows 7 had `C:\` locked down IIRC.

Comment: @MSalters its actually windows 7 Prof. However my account is in the "administrators" group. So is the "User" account (whatever that is). The permissions on c: are: "authenticated users: none", "SYSTEM: full control", "admins: full control", "Users: read+execute only".... I assume that when I run Rhapsody it runs at my user level?... still a bit confused on that :o

Comment: @MSalters hmmm... on another PC, also win7, I am not an admin and I can still make a folder in c:\  ...

Comment: Thinking a bit closer about that, those are ACL's. Elevation is a security property of processes, and the (single) user account running a process is a second property. The ACL lists security properties of files, and as you can see an ACL can contain entries for multiple users _and groups_ .Mind you, _Administrators_ is a group. Administrator is a user account. They are _not_ the same.